# Telegram: periodic profile photo changes using Telethon causing FloodWaitError

Tags: telethon

I'm running provided code to change my profile photo periodically (1 time per 2 minutes).
After some time (5-6 hrs) I'm starting to get FloodWaitError, while calling  `UploadProfilePhotoRequest` though I couldn't find any Telegram API rate limits for doing that.

Any idea if Telegram has some undocumented rate limits for updating profile photos or something is wrong with my code?

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.photos import UploadProfilePhotoRequest, DeletePhotosRequest

config = {
    API_ID: '123456', 
    API_HASH: '123qwezxc123qwezxc123qwezxc'
}

def getImageFileName():
    # some logic to get image file name
    return 'SomeImageFile.png'

async def main():
    prev_avatar = await client.get_profile_photos('me')
    filename = getImageFileName()

    # delete old profile photo
    await client(DeletePhotosRequest(prev_avatar))

    # load new profile photo
    file = await client.upload_file(filename)
    await client(UploadProfilePhotoRequest(
        file = file    
    ))

client = TelegramClient(session_path + '/' + config.PHONE, config.API_ID, config.API_HASH).start(phone=config.PHONE)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```